# Retrieving a user's job post count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't get the current user's post count. I have read the `Laravel 5's` docs and nothing works.

What do work is to show the total amount of users with 'x' job posts. I though this would work in the views:

`{{\Auth::user()->has('jobs', '<=', '4')->count() }}`

I have played around in tinker but nothing works. Am I missing something in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer!

```
{{ \Auth::user()->jobs->count() }}
```